# How to save a QPixmap as a picture in a folder with C++ and Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to code a C++ function to save a selected picture to my program directory, using a Qt GUI.

So far, the "save" function I'm using on my QPixmap object won't save anything, and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code :

```
qImage = new QPixmap(path);
QPixmap qImage2 = qImage->scaled(this->width(),this->height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

qImage2.toImage();

qImage2.save(QDir::currentPath());
qDebug()<<QDir::currentPath();
```

Can anyone help me ? :)

Comment: Could it be that the program doesn't have a permission to write to `currentPath`? Is it on Windows? If so, try saving to "C:/User/.../Downloads", for example. I don't see any problems with your code, although it's weird that you use `QPixmap` which is designed specifically for accelerated rendering on screen. If possible, you should stick to `QImage` instead.

Comment: This was actually just the filename missing, but thank you because although it wasn't the problem, I didn't think about writing permissions and it could have been the hiccup!

Comment: Dang, I didn't notice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`QDir::currentPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#currentPath) returns the current working **directory**. Obviously, the **filename** itself is not specified. Simply append the needed filename, for example: `QDir::currentPath() + "/123.png"`
- [`QPixmap::toImage()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#toImage) is a const method returning a `QImage` converted from a `QPixmap`. It literally does nothing useful in your code, remove it or use `QImage` instead.
- [`QDir::currentPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#currentPath) returns the current working directory which is **not** necessarily an application executable directory. Use [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) instead if you need an executable directory.
- Also, as pointed out by *Violet Giraffe*, there could be write permission issues.